# What is this: "->" in Drupal?

Tags: php, drupal

I am running into this `->` in Drupal and cant find any docs on it.

I am using it like this print `$node->content['field_pr_link'];`

is it a Drupal thing or PHP?

Comment: This is basic PHP OO syntax covered in PHP manual and the many existing PHP learning resources.

Comment: did we not answer your question?

Answer (score 10):

It's PHP. You are using it to access the content field on the node object.

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 1):

That is the PHP "Operator Object". It is very poorly documented in the PHP manual. It allows you to reference the variables, constants, and methods of an object.

```
$a = $ObjectInstance->var; # get variable or constant
$ObjectInstance->var2 = "string"; # set variable
$ObjectInstance->method(); # invoke a method.
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an operator used in scope of object to access its variables and methods.

Imagine having class as follows:

```
class Object {
    protected $variable;

    public function setVariable($variable) {
        $this->variable = $variable;
    }

    public function getVariable() {
        return $this->variable;
    }
}
```

You can see I'm accessing variables in scope of this class (`$this`) using `->` operator. When I create instance, I'll be able to access also public methods / variables from the same scope, using the same operator:

```
$object = new Object();
$object->setVariable('Hello world');
echo $object->getVariable(); // 'Hello world'
```

In your case `$node` represents an object and `content` is public variable inside that object.